# How can I calculate the relative lengths of triangle sides if all angles are known?

Tags: triangles, pythagorean-triples

I've read about this on other occasions on here before but I think my problem isn't a duplicate.

I'm trying to find the lengths of sides of a triangle where I know all three angles.

Let's say $A = 60^\circ$, $B = 90^\circ$, $C = 30^\circ$ and $b = 1cm$.

How can I find the lengths of $A$ and $C$ without using [the law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) for any angle triangle where $B = 90^\circ$ and $b = 1cm$?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the law of sines? It's practically made for that kind of task.

Comment: Why ?  What's wrong with using the law of sines ?

Comment: @Troposphere I'm doing it in a programming language which doesn't have a `sin()` function.

Comment: (In this particular case the triangle is right, so there are more specific trigonometric rules to apply, but they're what the law of sines boils down to anyway once you know that $\sin 90^\circ = 1$).

Comment: @Troposphere I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that all the triangles are right.

Comment: If only the angle $B$ is fixed at $90^\circ$ but $A$ and $C$ can vary, there's no way out of using a trigonometric function _somehow_. You get $a = \cos C$ and $c=\sin C$ -- if you can compute _one_ of those you can find the other with Pythagoras and a square root, but (by definition!) being able to compute the first one means you're computing a sine or cosine. You may have to code your own implementation (perhaps a more or less approximate one), but that's what it amounts to.

Comment: If you're curious, there's a whole body of work out there on how to approximate sines & cosines without a dedicated sine & cosine function;  modern algorithms don't just use Taylor series (though they're definitely used, and they'll do the trick if you've got clock cycles to spare.)  [There's a nice discussion of this over on the mothership.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662261/fastest-implementation-of-sine-cosine-and-square-root-in-c-doesnt-need-to-b)

Comment: If the  side opposite the right angle is $1$, then
$x=\cos A$ and $y=\sin A$.

Comment: Y9u just want ratios but
$(87363,151316,174725)\space \approx  59.9998106752595^\circ$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Taylor Series for Trigonometric Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Trigonometric_functions).

You will have to convert the angles (measured in degrees) to angles (measured in radians), where $180^\circ = \pi~$ radians.

Then, you can use the linked article to express the sine function to any desired degree of accuracy that your software/hardware can handle.  In fact, I suspect that programs such as Java and C, that do have the sine
function do the exact same thing.

Once you are able to have your own estimation of the sine function, for any pertinent angle $(\theta)$, then (assuming that $b$ represents the hypotenuse), it is a simple matter to compute (for example) $b\sin(\theta).$

Comment: I think there is a typo. `... convert the angles to angles...`

Comment: @gurkensaas No, no typo.  It is true that in Real Analysis (AKA Calculus) the domain of the sine and cosine functions are real numbers that represent the arc length of a specific arc of the unit circle.  However, when you transition from Analytical Geometry to the first week of Calculus, you are introduced to the (somewhat ambiguous) notion of a Radian as an alternative unit of measure for angles.  This analogizes to measurements of length being expressible in either feet, or inches.  ...see next comment

Comment: @gurkensaas Although Taylor Series applications around trig functions almost always require that the domain of the trig function be a real number, this specific situation is a **rare** exception.  Therefore, for simplicity, you can stay within the simplified world of the domain of trig functions being angles measured in Radians, with the Real number part of the angle measurement applied to the Taylor series.  Unusual, but perhaps easiest for an Analytical Geometry-Calculus newbie to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [Bhaksara I's sine approximation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhaskara_I%27s_sine_approximation_formula):
$$
\sin x^\circ \approx \frac{4x(180-x)}{40500 - x(180-x)}
$$
where $x$ is measured in degrees.  This gives a result that is accurate to within about $\pm 0.0015$ over the entire range of angles from $0$ to $180°$.  The fractional error maxes out at a little less than 2% near $0°$ and $180°$.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I already implemented the Taylor series which produces the desired results to about 8 decimal points.